# User Does Not Contain A Definition For Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am attempting a simple assignment of a string to the current user ID in a service class like so:

```
strCurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

//My namespace references
using HelpDesk.DAL;
using HelpDesk.Models;
using HelpDesk.ViewModels;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

Where `User.Identity.GetUserId` is accessed via the `System.Security.Principal` class.

Visual Studio keeps thinking I am trying to access a model type `User` that I do have in my project by this is not what I am trying to call.

This exact line of code works in another class, but not this one and I don't know why.

Comment: Is the other class where it works a `Controller` by any chance?

Comment: Yea it definitely is

Comment: That' clearly not C!

Comment: Ah, I apologise, I must have mis-clicked. I definitely meant to enter C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`User`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user(v=vs.118).aspx) is a property of the `Controller` class which is why you cannot 'see' it from another class.

You have a couple of options:

1. Pass the `User` value to your other class, for example:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       public void SomeMethod(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user)
       {
           //do something with 'user'
       }
   }

   public ActionResult SomeAction()
   {
       var myClass = new MyClass();
       myClass.SomeMethod(User);
   }
   ```
2. You can also retrieve the user from the `HttpContext`. The `HttpContext` class has [a static method to get the current context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

   ```
   var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second approach.